# Write two subscript on the thermodynamic functions

Tags: chemmacros

In the thermodynamic module of `\chemmacro`, I would like to be able to define two subscript one on the left of the function and the other on the right as in the image below

[image]

I try

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}

\RenewChemState\enthalpy{ subscript-left = ,subscript-right =  , unit=\joule} \par

\begin{document}
\enthalpy(r)(1){}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\usepackage[modules={all}]{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula,greek=mathdesign}

\RenewChemState\enthalpy{ symbol=H, subscript-left = ,subscript-right =  , unit=\joule}
\begin{document}
    \state_r{H}_1^0 = \qty{6}{\joule} \hspace{2cm}  
    \enthalpy(r, subscript-right= 1, superscript=0){6}
\end{document}
```

The `chemmacros` modules are now loaded as an option. The options in the new `ChemState` are loaded as comma delimited options.

[image: enthalpy]

*Note:* I obtain the same result using this line to define a new `ChemState`:

```
\RenewChemState\enthalpy{ symbol=H, unit=\joule}
```

The entry `symbol=H` is essential, the subscript entries aren't.

*Note 2:* to use arguments in the `enthalpy` function a new command needs to be defined. For example like this:

```
\newcommand{\argenthalpy}[4]{\chemDelta $_{\text{#1}}H_{#2}^{#3}$ = \qty{#4}{\joule} }
```

When used this command accepts four arguments placed in curly brackets like this:

```
\argenthalpy{r}{1}{0}{6}
```

The output is the same as the other two examples.

Comment: I don't understand the note: when I test to set the new Chemstate, I don't get the correct result. 
The principle of the `\state` command is good (and works) but it is less understandable than using the `\enthalpy` command

Comment: I use LuaLaTeX, so I had to comment out the `fontec` and `inputenc` packages, but I don't think that would have any influence. Do you have a fully update distribution? Especially the `chemmacros` and `siunitx` (loaded by the *themodynamics* module) packages?

Comment: I think I misspoke: the commands work. It's just that using the `\state` command is less readable than using the `\enthalpy` command (we know what we're talking about directly). So I was wondering if by redefining a new `\enthalpy` command, we couldn't make two indices appear (without having to specify tthe settings like in your example `\enthalpy(r, subscript-right= 1, superscript=0){6}` each time the command is called (I have several times to write it so if I could make it easier for myself to write)

Comment: I understand. You actually want something like `subscript-right=#2, `superscript=#3`. As far as I know #1 is locked into `subscript-left` since you aren’t allowed to use that setting in the option part of the `\enthalpy` … You could try and see if `\RenewChemState\enthalpy[3]{ symbol = H, subscript-left=#1, subscript-right=#2, superscript=#3, …}` would work.

Comment: @Nicolas I found a possible solution using four arguments and typesetting as `\ChemState`. See *Note 2* in my answer.

Comment: thanks. I modified the command a bit to take into account the fact that the 4th parameter can be empty and in this case does not display a numerical value : `\newcommand{\argenthalpy}[4]{
\ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{\chemDelta $_{\text{#1}}H_{#2}^{#3}$}{\chemDelta $_{\text{#1}}H_{#2}^{#3}$ = \qty{#4}{\joule}}
}`